# Screenshot return as black image xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimage, screenshot

I am using `Zxing` library to generate barcodes. I am trying to capture that barcodes to store for future reference.

I have created custom barcode view. And implemented renderer for iOS and Android. But in iOS, image comes as a black image. I tried many codes from internet but without success.

Can you please tell me what is wrong in this code ?

**Custom BarcodeView**

```
public class BarcodeView : StackLayout
{
    public EventHandler OnDrawBitmap;

    public static readonly BindableProperty BarcodeUrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BarcodeUrl),
       typeof(string),
       typeof(string),
       default(string));

    public string BarcodeUrl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BarcodeUrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarcodeUrlProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

**Xaml Implementation**

```
<custom:BarcodeView Opacity="0" x:Name="barcodeview"><!---->                             
        <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView  x:Name="QRCodeView" BarcodeFormat="CODE_93"
                HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="800" BarcodeValue="{Binding RandomBarcodeNumber}"  VerticalOptions="Center">
               <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                    <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="800" Height="200"/>
               </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
          </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView>                             
</custom:BarcodeView>
```

**iOS Renderer**

```
public class BarcodeViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<BarcodeView, UIView>
{
    public BarcodeViewRenderer()
    {
    }

    BarcodeView view;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BarcodeView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            //register the event
            e.NewElement.OnDrawBitmap += NewElement_OnDrawBitmap;
        }
    }

    private void NewElement_OnDrawBitmap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {               
            var formsView = Element;
            var rect = new CGRect(formsView.Bounds.X, formsView.Bounds.Y, formsView.Bounds.Width, formsView.Bounds.Height);
            var iOSView = ConvertFormsToNative(formsView, rect);
            UIImage image = ConvertViewToImage(iOSView);

            if (image != null)
                formsView.BarcodeUrl = image.AsPNG().GetBase64EncodedString(Foundation.NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.EndLineWithLineFeed);
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private UIImage ConvertViewToImage(UIView iOSView)
    {
        try
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(iOSView.Bounds.Size,true, 0);
            iOSView.DrawViewHierarchy(iOSView.Bounds, true);
            var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            iOSView.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
            var img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            return img;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
    {
        var renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view);

        renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;
        renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
        renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());
        var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;
        nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

        return nativeView;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: @MihailDuchev I am using `2.4.1` of zxing library. but I think this is not the problem of zxing library. I am missing somthing in ios code